# Why does my jQuery Validation require 2 clicks to invoke?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, ajax, jquery-ui

I have a comments form with 2 fields in it: Author and Message. When I click the submit button the validation does not fire. If i click the submit button once more, then the validation works. Any idea why?

```
//User Clicked Submit Button
$('#CommentsForm').live('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //Prevent Browser from getting new url

    //Validate the comments form
    $('#CommentsForm').validate({
        rules: {
            Author: "required",
            Message: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            Author: "Author is required.",
            Message: "Comment is required."
        },
        errorContainer: "#CommentsErrorBox",
        errorLabelContainer: "#CommentsErrorBox ul",
        wrapper: "li",

        submitHandler: function() {
            //Create JSON object
            var jsonCommentData = {
                ProductID: $('#HiddenProductID').val(),
                Author: $('#Author').val(),
                Message: $('#Message').val()
            };

            //Add the comment.
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/_CommentsAdd',
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify(jsonCommentData),
                dataType: 'html',
                contentType: 'application/json',

                //The request was a success. Repopulate the div with new result set.
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#AjaxComments').html(data);
                    $('abbr.timeago').timeago(); //update the timestamp with timeago

                    //Change colors of message.                
                    if ($('#CommentStatus').html() == "Your Comment Has Been Added!") {
                        $('#CommentStatus').css('color', 'GREEN');
                    }
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert('Fail');
                }
            });
        }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your first click on `#CommentsForm` sets up jQuery validate:

```
$('#CommentsForm').validate({ ... });
```

Thus, any subsequent clicks are validated.

Fix:

```
    //setup validation
var form = $('#CommentsForm');

form.validate({ /* ... setup code .... */ }); 

form.live('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //Prevent Browser from getting new url

    $(this).validate();

});
```

Comment: Thank you. That resolved the double clicking issue. How can I invoke the validation again after the form has been submitted? For instance, say the user fills out all fields then submits the form, after a successful submission the user erases the values and tries to submit the form again with no values. In this case, the validation is not working as it did on the first submit. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: use the `validate` method and the `isValid` property appropropriately. calling `validate` sets the `isValid` property - this should set you on your way ...